# How best to use GNU parallel for jobs using a lot of CPU time

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Im trying to write an more efficient pipeline for my ChIP-seq analysis - after I discovered GNU parallel (thumbs up).

my script is long and enters a bottleneck when I have to call peaks with a program called MACS2 ( https://github.com/taoliu/MACS/ ).

First of all, Macs2 sometimes run for 4 hours (real time), second in a for loop I run 7 Macs2 calls and third I have to do this on 47 files containing between 10-100 millions of lines.

Initially I used something like:

`for item in ${data}; do
   macs2 callpeak (...)
   macs2 callpeak (...)
   macs2 callpeak (...)
   macs2 callpeak (...)
   macs2 callpeak (...)
   macs2 callpeak (...)
   macs2 callpeak (...)
   wait
done`

However as the run time of each call is varying a lot - this is of cause NOT efficient ! Further hardcoding the number of jobs running and not launching more if n=15 is NOT an option ... because Im afraid of thrashing the cluster!

I should mention that I'm working on a cluster with 20 cores available, of which I ONLY wish to use 15, each handling only 1 job and non of these 15 cores should be unused as long as there are files. Also it is normal to launch Big jobs with qsub in my group. IS GNU parallel compatible with sub or is the latter redundant when using parallel?

Trying to modify current approach using GNU parallel Im confused as to which approach I should use:

- command line call with all files piped into parallel, so that max 15 files are running in parallel where macs2 is running one after another for each file?
  `find . -name "*bam" | parallel -j 15 myscript.sh`
- make a function and then use GNU parallel INSIDE script in 7 subsequent steps, like:

`macs(){
    macs2 callpeak (...)
}
export -f

1. parallel -j 15 macs {} ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
2. parallel -j 15 macs {} ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
..
7. parallel -j 15 macs2 {} ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 ...`

Where arg1 is the file list and >arg1 are macs2 parameter settings

Also if looping over all files I not sure if Im better of with sem: 
`parallel --semaphore --id pipeline1 -j 20` 
However with this methodology I don't know how to pass BOTH the macs2 program AND macs2's parameters to parallel as I understand that seem do not take -a ::: and :::: as input.

Hope that so one could guide in better direction - And that I made my self clear.

Thanks in advance & Kind regards,
Isolde

Answer (score 2):

```
parallel -j15 macs2 callpeak -t {} -c Control.bam -f BAM -g hs -n test -B -q 0.01 ::: *.bam
```

Comment: Hi Ole. Thank you for your reply. So if I run this inside my script (with different parameter, control and output settings) I can make 7 subsequent calls to macs .. where the first will be complete after the 47 files have been processed and then the second call to macs will run etc. ? appreciate your help - thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand your comment. I will recommend you walk through the tutorial: man parallel_tutorial